# Nginx reverse proxy for node.js error Failed to lookup view "default" in views directory

Tags: node.js, nginx

I am wants using Nginx as reverse proxy for my express.js app.

here is my nginx config :

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name  my server ip address;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://myip:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

and its my app.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var app = express();

app.set('view engine' , 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/song', function(req, res, next) {

   // my route
}
```

without nginx my app works very well but when i using nginx as reverse proxy and go to my `song` route node give me this error : `Failed to lookup view "default" in views directory`

i want know where i am wrong. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem after configuring Nginx server. I found the solution.

The node couldn't able to find the path for the "views" folder in the project. so define the path.

```
var path = require("path");

app.set('view engine' , 'ejs');
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
```